# Select Date Time Difference in Minutes which is Less than Particular Minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) as Mtime 
       FROM Transaction_tbl t WHERE Locid=6
```

This will return result like:

```
Mtime
8
2
10
20
15
7
6
```

But, in that query I have to give condition like I want to show result like less than 10 minutes or less than 15 minutes only .
I have one more table which is **location**. In that, I have a column **timeinterval** with data type **Time(0)**. Actually this value I want to pass in the same query.
So how I can re-write my query showing result less than 10 minutes?

Comment: Just add WHERE clause in your query. Like this: "Where DATEDIFF(minute,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) < 10"

Answer (score 5):

Add `AND` condition in `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT  
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.Paydate, t.DelDate) AS Mtime 
FROM Transaction_tbl t 
WHERE 
    Locid = 6
    AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) < 10
```

As per your new doubt:

```
SELECT  
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.Paydate, t.DelDate) AS Mtime,
    COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM Transaction_tbl t 
WHERE 
    Locid = 6
GROUP BY Mtime
HAVING DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.Paydate, t.DelDate) < 10
```

you can do something like this

```
SELECT  
   case when ( DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.Paydate, t.DelDate)<10) then DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.Paydate, t.DelDate) else null end AS lessthan10,
case when ( DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.Paydate, t.DelDate)>10) then DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.Paydate, t.DelDate) else null end AS greaterthan10,
    COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM Transaction_tbl t 
WHERE 
    Locid = 6
GROUP BY Mtime
HAVING DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.Paydate, t.DelDate) < 10
```

Comment: sir can i ask one more doubt?

Comment: I update my Answer Please Check it ...of-course You can ask..!!

Comment: now i have a two query one is less than 10 minute and one is greater than 10 minute.but i want to show result in same row

Comment: sir u got my question??

Comment: my query like this:   
 select COUNT( DATEDIFF(minute,t.Paydate,t.DelDate))  as OnTime from Transaction_tbl t where Locid=6 and Status=5 and DATEDIFF(minute,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) < 1  
  select COUNT( DATEDIFF(minute,t.Paydate,t.DelDate))  as Violate from Transaction_tbl t where Locid=6 and Status=5 and DATEDIFF(minute,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) > 1

Comment: You have no common column  in both select query so can't use the join as per my knowledge you can only go through  case When which i suggest in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70021/discussion-between-user3252014-and-dhaval).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
WITH CTE(Mtime) As (
select DATEDIFF(minute,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) as Mtime 
from Transaction_tbl  t
)
Select Mtime from 
CTE
Where Mtime < 10
```

Reference : [Using Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)